# Dynamic content within journey builder using Live Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dynamic-content

I'd like to use the Lookup function (Lookup(1,2,3,4,[5a,5b]...) ) within an email while in Journey builder to generate dynamic content.
  Is there a way to name the data extension (field '1' in the lookup function) so that the lookup function will reference the Live version of the data extension as opposed to the version of the data extension as it existed when the subscriber was injected into the journey?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your data extension is linked in the Data Designer to your Contact record, you should be fine.

[Look at the documentation outlined here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data.htm&type=5).